# hibernate.cfg.xml already exists in my project but I'm getting this error hibernate.cfg.xml not found

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets, classloader

I am getting the above mentioned error.I have the xml file hibernate.cfg.xml already within the web application. As well as this I have the full jar files required for hibernate under WebINF lib folder.

[image: Here's my hibernate.cfg.xml listed in the project]

[image: Here's a list of jar files including hibernate jars]

Here's the full error

```
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin/client;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/bin;C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre7/lib/i386;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\JavaSE7\Tomcat7\apache-tomcat-7.0.29\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_05\bin;C:\JavaSE7\eclipse;;.
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:18 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:CricketWebApplication' did not find a matching property.
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:18 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebApp' did not find a matching property.
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:18 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:SimpleServlet' did not find a matching property.
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:18 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:Struts2Starter' did not find a matching property.
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:18 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.server:WebProjTemplate' did not find a matching property.
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:18 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:18 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 615 ms
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:18 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.50
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://displaytag.sf.net/el is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://displaytag.sf.net is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:24 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://displaytag.sf.net/el is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://displaytag.sf.net is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/core is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt_rt is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/fmt is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/permittedTaglibs is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://jakarta.apache.org/taglibs/standard/scriptfree is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql_rt is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/sql is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml_rt is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jstl/xml is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TaglibUriRule body
INFO: TLD skipped. URI: http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml is already defined
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8090"]
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Mar 11, 2014 4:11:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 10062 ms
Mar 11, 2014 4:12:12 PM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
Mar 11, 2014 4:12:12 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: Hibernate 3.2.5
Mar 11, 2014 4:12:12 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: hibernate.properties not found
Mar 11, 2014 4:12:12 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
INFO: Bytecode provider name : cglib
Mar 11, 2014 4:12:12 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
Mar 11, 2014 4:12:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
INFO: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Mar 11, 2014 4:12:13 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
INFO: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
Mar 11, 2014 4:12:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [com.webapp.servlet.SignUpServlet] in context with path [/CricketWebApplication] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
org.hibernate.HibernateException: /hibernate.cfg.xml not found
    at org.hibernate.util.ConfigHelper.getResourceAsStream(ConfigHelper.java:147)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.getConfigurationInputStream(Configuration.java:1405)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1427)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:972)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:69)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:1414)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.configure(AnnotationConfiguration.java:966)
    at com.webapp.util.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:16)
    at com.webapp.servlet.SignUpServlet.doProcess(SignUpServlet.java:68)
    at com.webapp.servlet.SignUpServlet.doGet(SignUpServlet.java:35)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:409)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1044)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Try putting the xml file directly under the src folder

Comment: Did check in folder it's under src already but it's not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to understand what all directory will actually end up in classpath and where and as your logs suggests that the configuration files is being looked at root of classpath, whereas your config file is actually in com.webapp.util package from root of class path. So putting the config directly under src folder should work.

To verify you can look into the build path of your project and go to location where the classes are output. Your config folder should end up at root.

Answer (score 1):

try to put it in src directory rather than com.webapp.util package.or make resource directory and put your hibernate.cfg.xml in that directory.

Comment: Did check in folder it's under src already but it's not being found it's under src directory when I checked in folder

Comment: Check whether the classes output folder has the config file at its root. You probably need to clean the project again.